# Search for pattern and append line to another file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file like this (five tab-separated columns)

```
head allKO.txt
Metabolism Carbohydrate metabolism Glycolisis K07448
Metabolism Protein metabolism protesome K02217
```

and I want to search for the pattern (string) in column 5 in the file `KEGG.annotations`, and, if it is found, I want to print in another file both the line from `KEGG.annotations` where the pattern was found and all the columns of `allKO.txt`.
The file where I'm looking for the pattern is:

```
head KEGG.annotations
>aai:AARI_24510  proP; proline/betaine transporter; K03762 MFS transporter, MHS family, proline/betaine transporter
>aai:AARI_26600  ferritin-like protein; K02217 ferritin [EC:1.16.3.1]
>aai:AARI_28260  hypothetical protein
>aai:AARI_29060  ABC drug resistance transporter, inner membrane subunit; K09686 antibiotic transport system permease protein
>aai:AARI_29070  ABC drug resistance transporter, ATP-binding subunit (EC:3.6.3.-); K09687 antibiotic transport system ATP-binding protein
>aai:AARI_29650  hypothetical protein
>aai:AARI_32480  iron-siderophore ABC transporter ATP-binding subunit (EC:3.6.3.-); K02013 iron complex transport system ATP-binding protein [EC:3.6.3.34]
>aai:AARI_33320  mrr; restriction system protein Mrr; K07448 restriction system protein
```

I want something like this:

```
Metabolism Carbohydrate metabolism Glycolisis K07448 >aai:AARI_33320 mrr; restriction system protein Mrr; K07448 restriction system
Metabolism Protein metabolism proteasome K02217  >aai:AARI_26600 ferritin-like protein; K02217 ferritin [EC:1.16.3.1]
```

Note that the `>aai:AARI_33320 mrr; restriction …` text that is appended to the first line is eighth line from `KEGG.annotations`, which is the one that contains `K07448` (which is the ID field (fifth field) from the first line of `allKO.txt`).

How can I modify this code in order to use my pattern file? This works with a pattern file with only one column containing the specific pattern to find.

```
while read pat; do
    grep "$pat" --label="$pat" -H < KEGG.annotations;
done < allKO.txt > test1
```

Comment: Show difference between allKO.txt and what you want. In present it's much difficult to find it out.

Comment: I can't understand what you want. Your output looks identical to `allKO.txt`. The third column of `allKO.txt` is the word `metabolism`, that pattern doesn't appear anywhere in `KEGG.annotations`.

Comment: @Barmar the file allKO.txt is a sort of database. In the file kegg., I have the annotations of my genes (within the string I have the ID starting with K0). The same IDs are in the third column of allKO.txt. The first Lines of the output I want are just an example, not all the KO in allKO.txt will be present in kegg.annotation

Comment: I want to search for the ID in column 3 of allKO in kegg.annotations and if found, I want to add the other columns of allKO

Comment: It seems not to be clear where the column boundaries are in allKO.txt. To me it looke like this for the first line: Column 1 = `Metabolism`, Column 2 = `Carbohydrate`, Column 3 = `metabolism`, Column 4 = `Glycolisis`, Column 5 = `K07488`. So if you want to search for the pattern in column 3, you want to search for `metabolism`. If that's not what you mean, please clarify the question.

Comment: No, actually the 1 column is metabolim, 2=Carbohydrates metabolism 3=Glycolisis 4=K0... The four columns are tab delimited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with the code you already have. Store the line into an array and match for the fifth element:

```
while read -r line; do
    [ -z "$line" ] && continue
    patlist=($line)
    pat=${patlist[4]}
    grep "$pat" --label="$line" -H < KEGG.annotations
done < allKO.txt
```

returns:

```
Metabolism Carbohydrate metabolism Glycolisis K07448:>aai:AARI_33320  mrr; restriction system protein Mrr; K07448 restriction system protein
Metabolism Protein metabolism protesome K02217:>aai:AARI_26600  ferritin-like protein; K02217 ferritin [EC:1.16.3.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you seem to be asking for:

```
while read w1 w2 w3 w4 ID
do
    printf "%s " "$w1 $w2 $w3 $w4 $ID"
    if ! grep "$ID" KEGG.annotations
    then
        echo
    fi
done < allKO.txt
```

This will write output to the screen. 
Add an output (`>`) redirection (e.g., `> test1`) to the last line
to capture the output in a file.

- Based on your examples, the key/ID field (“pattern”)
  is the *fifth* of *five* fields in the `allKO.txt` file, so we `read w1 w2 w3 w4 ID`. 
  You say this is a tab-delimited file; I’m assuming that none of the fields contain spaces.
- Write (`printf`) the line (i.e., the fields) from `allKO.txt`,
  with a space at the end but no terminating newline.
- Search (`grep`) the `KEGG.annotations` file for the ID
  (fifth field from the line from `allKO.txt`). 
  These will be complete lines (including newlines).
- If the `grep` fails, write a newline, since the `printf` didn’t.
- This will result in lines whose ID isn’t present in `KEGG.annotations`
  to be simply written to the output:

  ```
  Metabolism Protein metabolism proteasome K02217  >aai:AARI_26600 ferritin-like protein; K02217 ferritin [EC:1.16.3.1]
  This ID doesn’t exist: K99999
  ```

  and IDs that exist more than once are written as additional lines
  (not repeating the data from `allKO.txt`):

  ```
  Metabolism Protein metabolism proteasome K02217  >aai:AARI_26600 ferritin-like protein; K02217 ferritin [EC:1.16.3.1]
  This is a hypothetical additional line from KEGG.annotations that mentions “K02217”.
  ```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the suggestion, but it's not exactly what I need. The file allKO has 1 million rows and many of the ID are not present in my kegg.annotations, so I don't want to add so many Lines that I don't need. Then many ID in allKO are present several Times in kegg.annotations and I need them to be printed with all the other information more than once